# Layer SetNeedsDisplay issue in iOS 4.0

Tags: ios4

I am working on PDF viewer on iOS, calling [TiledLayer setNeedsDisplay] invalidates display region well in iOS 3.X version. The same code doesn't work on iOS 4.0 onwards. I searched thru forum, None of them helped me.

Could anyone point some clue to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior.  Might be worth submitting a bug to Apple.

Comment: I'm in trouble just like you! did you find any solution?